# Changing the parent of instantiated object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I want to change the parent of an instantiated object but I'm getting hung up on something. I'm getting an error but I'm not sure what it exactly means: Assets/_Scripts/InstantiateSymbol.cs(29,73): error CS0176: Static member `UnityEngine.GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag(string)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with a type name instead

Where am I off? Still learning 8/

```
public GameObject symbolCharacter;

#region IPointerClickHandler implementation

public void OnPointerClick (PointerEventData eventData)
{
    // Instantiate an object on Click
    symbolCharacter = Instantiate(Resources.Load ("Prefabs/Symbols/SymbolImage1")) as GameObject;
    symbolCharacter.transform.parent = transform.gameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MessagePanel");
}

#endregion
```

Comment: Is FindGameObjectWithTag static method?

Comment: @AdilMammadov given the error message, it must be.

Comment: Ok. He found answer, but then the code in question should not compile @phoog

Comment: @AdilMammadov but the code in question *did not compile!*  The error reported in the question is a compiler error, not a run-time exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, Got it! Captital 'G' GameObject and I should be using SetParent instead.

```
public GameObject symbolCharacter;

#region IPointerClickHandler implementation

public void OnPointerClick (PointerEventData eventData)
{
    // Instantiate an object on Click
    symbolCharacter = Instantiate(Resources.Load ("Prefabs/Symbols/SymbolImage1")) as GameObject;
    symbolCharacter.transform.SetParent(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MessagePanel").transform);
}

#endregion
```